# How do I read sequence data in Scala in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sequence

This is my first time to attempt to read sequence format data in Scala, it would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me with the right command.

data:

```
hdfs dfs -cat orders03132_seq/part-m-00000 | head
SEQ!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritableordeG�Y���&���]E�@��
```

My command:

```
sc.sequenceFile("orders03132_seq/part-m-00000", classOf[Int], classOf[String]).first
```

Error:

> 18/03/13 16:59:28 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0
>   (TID 1) java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: WritableName
>   can't load class: orders
>           at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.getValueClass(SequenceFile.java:2103)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you format your code properly? Cannot make out what's the output of `hdfs dfs -cat orders03132_seq/part-m-00000 | head`.

Comment: sorry about that, did you already format it for me? I don't see any weirdo now, but thank you reminder, I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: It's not been edited and at least for me has garbage after `SEQ!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritableordeG`

Comment: Thanks. Those are not garbage, indeed, they are the content of the sequence file

Answer (score 1):

You would need to read it as a Hadoop File. You can do this with something like:

```
sc.hadoopFile[K, V, SequenceFileInputFormat[K,V]]("path/to/file")
```

Refer documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#hadoopFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-int-).

Comment: Can you advise what should I put as K and V there? According to the actual sequence data content, it seems indicating LongWritable, but if it is for K, what about V? Thank you.

Comment: It would be the Key and Value format of how you are storing the SequenceFile in the first place. I would guess you have K = Int, V = String from your code snippet. But I am not sure.